# Segmentation Fault em função que troca os valores de 2 strings

Tags: c, string, memória, falha-de-segmentação

A função a seguir troca (ou pelo menos deveria) o conteúdo de duas *strings*

```
void trocar(char *a, char *b){
    char *novo = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

    strcpy(novo, a);
    strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, novo);
}
```

Porém ao chamar a função na main, ocorre Segmentation Fault.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    char *a = "oi";
    char *b = "tchau";
    trocar(a, b);
    printf("a: %s, b: %s\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Eu não consegui entender o que está causando esse erro.

O que causa isso? E se possível, como seria uma função que troca o valor de duas strings corretamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não copiou para a área do seu código, então tentou trocar valores da área estática do código e esta é uma área apenas de leitura. O dado que está no seu código não está nem em memória automática, nem em memória dinâmica que é o que deseja mexer. Assim funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void trocar(char *a, char *b) {
    char *novo = malloc(10);
    strcpy(novo, a);
    strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, novo);
}

int main() {
    char *a = malloc(10);
    strcpy(a, "oi");
    char *b = malloc(10);
    strcpy(b, "tchau");
    trocar(a, b);
    printf("a: %s, b: %s\n", a, b);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IpKxbA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wbfwgslx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/SwapCopyHeap.c).

Mas a forma que se faz troca de verdade porque é mais eficiente seria usando só ponteiros:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void trocar(char **a, char **b) {
    char *novo = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = novo;
}

int main() {
    char *a = malloc(3);
    strcpy(a, "oi");
    char *b = malloc(6);
    strcpy(b, "tchau");
    trocar(&a, &b);
    printf("a: %s, b: %s\n", a, b);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oGXW0q). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hendmarf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/SwapPointerHeap.c).

Mas se quiser mesmo trocar o valor pelo menos deveria usar memória automática que é mais seguro e eficiente, a memória dinâmica deveria ser usada em último caso, e não parece ser necessário neste caso (só seria se tiver algo que não sei só vendo este código). Aí o dado já é colocando onde deve. Mas ainda faz cópia o que ainda é bem ineficiente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void trocar(char *a, char *b) {
    char novo[10];
    strcpy(novo, a);
    strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, novo);
}

int main() {
    char a[10] = "oi";
    char b[10] = "tchau";
    trocar(a, b);
    printf("a: %s, b: %s\n", a, b);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oGXW0q). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yatjbnwz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/SwapCopyStack.c).

Note que no seu exemplo tive que mudar a alocação de memória porque com a troca você tem que garantir que todos os envolvidos tenham espaço para o maior. Para um exemplo geral isto é muito mais complicado, para este exemplo o maior é 6, estamos vendo no código, mas você usou 10 no temporário, imagino que saiba o que está fazendo, que poderia mudar o código para ser mais que 6, mas não mais que 10 (9 caracteres usáveis). Então arrumei isso. E aí no exemplo da alocação no *stack* também tive que usar 10. Sim, há desperdício em ambos, o que neste caso muda pouco. Por isso a segunda solução também é a melhor neste aspecto de consumo de memória, é até mais conceitualmente correto, não é só eficiência.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Realmente, a segunda forma que você mostrou é eficiente e resolveu o meu problema. Valeu!